# Поиск по массиву JavaScript

Tags: javascript

У меня имеется массив на JS содержащий в себе числовые значения:

```
var massiv = [
    "100", "101", "456", "1000", "321"
]
```

И имеется переменная:

```
var peremennaya = "101"
```

Задача: 
если переменная совпадает с одним из значений массива то необходимо выполнить действие. Например:

```
alert = "Нашлось 101"
```

В массиве находятся исключительно числовые значения, но в кавычки обернуты они для универсальности, как мне кажется, т.е. чтобы скрипт не только сравнивал значения

```
==
```

но и находил буквенные совпадения.

Если можно, хотелось бы увидеться пример с пояснениями каждого шага в виде комментариев или как удобно.

Comment: Чисто ради интереса: почему посчитали, что написание лишнего кода с  for лучше, чем простой `indexOf`?

Comment: Цикл оказался более практичным, если переменная меняется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На примере цикла `for`

```js
var massiv = [
    "100", "101", "456", "1000", "321"
]
var peremennaya = "101";

for (i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {
if (peremennaya == massiv[i]) {
alert("Мы нашли "+massiv[i])
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var peremennaya = 101;
var massiv = [
    100, 101, 456, 1000, 321
];


if (massiv.indexOf(peremennaya) != -1)
  console.log('Массив содержит значение ' + peremennaya);
```

Тут и пояснять нечего. Метод **[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** возвращает первый индекс, по которому данный элемент может быть найден в массиве или -1, если такого индекса нет.

Более подробные и разнообразные примеры применения метода можно посмотреть по ссылке, указанной выше.

Answer (score 1):

вот на православном js есть спец функция поиска по критерию
**и если будет множественное вхождение элемента в массив**

```js
var peremennaya = 101 ;
var massiv = [100, 101, 456, 1000, 321];
var itog = massiv.filter(item => {
  return item === peremennaya; // тут логика сравнения 
});

console.log(itog);
```

Comment: Это фильтрация, а не поиск. Для конкретно поиска нужно заюзать `Array#find`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно с `Array.prototype.includes()`:

```
var testArray = [
    "100", "101", "456", "1000", "321"
]
var valueToFind= "101";

testArray.includes(valueToFind) ? console.log("find: "+ valueToFind) : console.log("we didn't find anything")
```

Comment: не подойдет для поиска объектов

Comment: @Grundy в задаче это и не требуется